# How to remove the Share/Embed/Info screen in JW Player

Tags: jwplayer

JWPlayer noobie here.

I'm using it as flash fallback for IE7/8.  Movie plays ok but at the end I get a Share/Embed/Info screen showing. It must be possible to get rid of it as I don't see it on any Longtail Video examples on their site. However, I can't see how to anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you download the player, uncheck "Include JW Viral Plugin" @ http://www.longtailvideo.com/